# I have a hard bricked nexus 7,

Tags: nexus-7

I have a hard bricked Asus nexus 7 i have tried everything can find to "unbrick" it.  i get to the google logo and thats as far as it gets. anyone got any ideas.

I can get to fastboot mode. I can move the choices from start to restart bootloader to recovery mode to power off to start. I have pressed the power button on each choice. if i hit start it goes to the google logo and freezes there. If i hit recovery mode it  goes to the google logo and no farther. hit restart bootloader comes back to start then hit the power button and the google logo comes up and freezes. same at the recovery mode. Power off is the only thing that works.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How did you brick it?

Comment: Sorry I haven't worked on my nexus 7 in a few day....Here is where i am. I have adb installed, up to date drivers and all the suggestion that were given above.

Comment: Here is where i am. I have adb installed, up to date drivers and all the suggestion that were given above. with no success. When I connect the N7 to my computer and check the device manager it shows my N7 as "Android device" when i open the "android device" folder it says "Android Bootloader interface". from a cmd prompt i run "adb devices"  the results is "List of devices attached" but there is nothing listed

Answer (score 0):

did you try to get an image for your nexus device from this place: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en and flash it ? If nothing is wrong with the hardware then this will help, just follow the steps provided on that page.

By the way, i've upgraded my nexus 7 to the latest Android 5.1.1 and i could not use it, because it keeps on freezing, rebooting. Had to downgrade back to 4.4.4 and now my device is back.

Comment: Here is a text file of the results i get when trying to unbrick my N7. The problem seems to lie with my device unable to be unlocked.

Comment: sending 'bootloader' (2308 KB)...
FAILED (remote: Bootloader is locked.)
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.007s]
finished. total time: 0.009s

sending 'radio' (12288 KB)...
FAILED (remote: Bootloader is locked.)
finished. total time: 0.010s
rebooting into bootloader...
sending 'boot' (4376 KB)...
FAILED (remote: Bootloader is locked.)
rebooting into bootloader...
sending 'recovery' (4924 KB)...
FAILED (remote: Bootloader is locked.)
erasing 'system'..

Comment: did you run "fastboot oem unlock" ?

Comment: I tried "unlock bootloader" using Nexus Root Toolkit v2.0.5 did not do anything. How do I run "fastboot oem unlock"

Comment: firstly, if you don't have it, then you need to get latest Android SDK tools from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other . Next step unpack downloaded archive file. Open command line (cmd) as administrator (right click on it), then in command line "cd " to the folder where you unpacked the android sdk, there must be tools folder, "cd tools". Then you need to run "android sdk" in your command line. The new window should be opened and there you need to select "Android Platform Tools" and install it. After installation close Android Sdk window and go back to command line,

Comment: type "cd ../platform-tools". Connect your Nexus device, and it should in a state when you see "Google" logo. Then you can execute "adb reboot bootloader", your device should reboot, if it was detected. If it rebooted successfully then you can execute "fastboot oem unlock".  Hope this would help , looks like you are doing it under Windows, i don't know the details how to work with android sdk on this platform, but it should be similar to what i've written above.