# Tried downgrading from 5.1.1 to 4.4.4 nexus 7, and it is bricked

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-7, nexus

As the title says, I rooted my Nexus 7, and it was working fine on 5.1.1 - albeit very very slowly - I got tired of the lag, and tried to downgrade to 4.4.4 following this [link](https://tektab.com/2015/10/23/downgrading-from-lolipop-to-kitkat-4-4-4-on-nexus-7-2012-model-nakasi/#comment-43654). The tablet went into bootloader(fastboot) mode, and stayed there for a long time. At this time I could cycle thru START, RESTART BOOTLOADER, POWER OFF, AND RECOVERY MODE options but NONE of them work except OFF. So I switched it off, and now, it does not boot up at all, not even in the recovery mode. It is just blank, I see no sign of life at all.
I cannot get it to start, so there is no way I can use ADB or Fastboot for this.
Is there any way I can solve this?
I already have adb/fastboot setup on my pc, but it does not recognize the tablet.
thanks for any help.
I did go thru the similar questions here - [link1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164845/is-there-any-way-to-fix-a-hard-bricked-nexus-7-when-it-cant-even-connect-to-the?newreg=d1f2831883ee4d238563f60e661b974b&answertab=createdasc#tab-top) - [link2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126570/i-have-a-hard-bricked-nexus-7). but they did not help.

Comment: Flashing Nexus devices is typically not a big problem. Therefore I assume your device has a hardware problem. Check the hardware keys if the are constantly pressed. If the device has a flash memory problem then the device is EOL. But 10 years would still be a good life time for a tablet.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have another Nexus 7, and it works flawlessly, on 4.4.4, having set it up as a digital clock. That also, I had rooted, and then unroot/stock with Nexus root toolkit. 
This nexus also I had rooted with the root kit, and it worked though very slowly. It was when I tried to downgrade that it completely broke.
Its 10 years, yes, but I would still like to use it as a music player, if it can be sorted out.